An error occurred when importing java native modules directly into the flutter plugin project
Why can't I find mylibrary when I already have it in settings.gradle include？
I tried to introduce it under the example->app project, which is normal. May I ask how to introduce it directly in the plug-in project? Importing jar packages is also normal.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
